# fetching XML through LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

In following WSDL(XML)

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns:tns="http://ttdev.com/ss"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"
     xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
     xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
     name="SecureService" targetNamespace="http://ttdev.com/ss">




     <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="p1">
         <sp:SignedParts>
         <sp:Body />
         </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:Policy>

        <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="p2">
         <sp:SignedParts>
         <sp:Body />
         </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:Policy>

    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="p3">
         <sp:SignedParts>
         <sp:Body />
         </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:Policy>

    <wsdl:binding name="SecureServiceSOAP" type="tns:SecureService">

    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

    <wsdl:operation name="concat">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#p1" wsdl:required="true" />
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://ttdev.com/ss/concat" />
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body parts="concatRequest" use="literal" />
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body parts="concatResponse" use="literal" />
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="SecureService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:SecureServiceSOAP" name="SecureServiceSOAP">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/SecureService" />
    </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

I want  to fetch following XML part from the XML

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="p1">
     <sp:SignedParts>
     <sp:Body />
     </sp:SignedParts>
</wsp:Policy>
```

I m writing followign LINQ Query

```
 XDocument wsdlDocument = XDocument.Load(_wsdlPath);

            XName operationElementName = XName.Get("operation", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/");
            XName policyReferenceElementName = XName.Get("PolicyReference", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy");
            XName policyElementName = XName.Get("Policy", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy");
            XName idAttributeName = XName.Get("id", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
 var operationPolicy = from policy in wsdlDocument.Descendants(policyElementName)
                                  where policy.Attribute(idAttributeName).Value == uritemp //uritemp = "p1"
                                  select policy.ToString();

            string resultingXML = operationPolicy.FirstOrDefault();
```

but it is not working , please tell me where I am making mistake.

Comment: The posted code seems to work fine. Can you elaborate on what error/exception/problem you are seeing?

Comment: I found the mistake in line XName idAttributeName = XName.Get("Id", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");  id is in small case in my xml where as in code it is in uppercase , how to make it case -insensitive

Comment: Xml attributes are case-sensitive ("Id" and "id" are two different attributes), so I don't see any way how you could write code that doesn't take the case into account...

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument wsdlDocument = XDocument.Load(_wsdlPath);

XName operationElementName = XName.Get(Constants.OPERATION, Constants.WSDL_NS);
XName policyReferenceElementName = XName.Get(Constants.POLICY_REFERENCE, Constants.NamespacePath.POLICY);
XName policyElementName = XName.Get(Constants.POLICY, Constants.NamespacePath.POLICY);
XName idAttributeName = XName.Get("Id", Constants.NamespacePath.WSSECURITY);


var uriNo = from operation in wsdlDocument.Descendants(operationElementName)
            where operation.HasAttributes && operation.Attribute(Constants.NAME).Value == _operationSelected
            from policyReference in operation.Descendants(policyReferenceElementName)
            where policyReference.HasAttributes && policyReference.Attribute(Constants.URI).Value.StartsWith(Constants.HASH)
            select policyReference.Attribute(Constants.URI).Value.Substring(1);

string uritemp = uriNo.FirstOrDefault().ToString();

var operationPolicy = from policy in wsdlDocument.Descendants(policyElementName)
                      where policy.HasAttributes && policy.Attribute(idAttributeName).Value == uritemp
                      select policy;

string temp = operationPolicy.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
return temp;
```